# Find a general solution to y'' + y = 0 using power series with x0=1

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I need a little help with the resolution of this EDO, when do I use this `x0 = 1`?Any idea?

Comment: A power series has the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$.  Assume $y$ has that form, differentiate it twice, plug in, simplify, and see what you get.

Comment: Maybe it's an ODE.. But what is $x_0$? Is it $y(0)=1$? And why you want to use  power series?

Comment: The OP must mean that he needs to use a power series about $x=1$ rather than the more common $x=0$.

Comment: @Jessy If Mark is correct then modify my power series expression to $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n$ and then continue as I described.

Answer (score 1):

Just a **Hint**

Put $z(x)=y(x+1)$ or $y(x)=z(x-1)$.

then

$y''+y=0 \iff z''+z=0$ with $z=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_nx^n$.

which gives

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}((n+1)(n+2)a_{n+2}+a_n)x^n=0$$

$$\implies  a_{n+2}=-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}a_{n}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $y''+y=0$ then you can differentiate both sides to get $y'''+y'=0$ and in turn $y^{(4)}+y''=0$.

Let $y^{(k)}_0$ denote the $k$-the derivative evaluated at $x=x_0$, i.e. $y^{(k)}(x_0)$.

If $y_0=a$ then $y''+y=0$ gives $y''_0=-a$. Similarly, $y^{(4)}+y''=0$ gives $y^{(4)}_0 = -y''_0 = a$. We can see that the even derivatives of $y$, evaluated at $x=x_0$ are given by $+a,-a,+a,-a,\ldots$

If $y_0'=b$ then $y'''+y'=0$ gives $y'''_0=-b$. Similarly, $y^{(5)}+y'''=0$ gives $y^{(5)}_0 = -y'''_0 = b$. We can see that the odd derivatives of $y$, evaluated at $x=x_0$ are given by $+b,-b,+b,-b,\ldots$

To be perfectly rigorous, we should use proof by induction to prove the derivatives alternate.

The power series of $y(x)$ close to $x=x_0$ is given by
$$y(x) \sim y_0+y_0'(x-x_0) + \frac{y''_0}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + \frac{y'''_0}{3!}(x-x_0)^3 + \cdots $$
In our case we have
$$y(x) \sim a + b(x-x_0)-\frac{a}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 - \frac{b}{3!}(x-x_0)^3 + \cdots $$
$$y(x) \sim a\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}(x-x_0)^2 + \cdots \right)+b\left( (x-x_0) - \frac{1}{3!}(x-x_0)^3 + \cdots \right)$$

You should notice that the series in the brackets look suspiciously like the Maclaurin series for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$, but for $x-x_0$ instead of $x$.

If we make the substitution $u=x-x_0$, then we see that
$$y(u+x_0) \sim a\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}u^2 + \cdots \right)+b\left( u - \frac{1}{3!}u^3 + \cdots \right)$$
meaning that $y(u+x_0) \sim a\cos u + b \sin u$ close to $u=0$.

In fact, since sine and cosine are analytic functions, we can drop the $\sim$ and say that $y(u+x_0) = a\cos u + b\sin u$ for all $u$.